# Phone won't update to compatible API level

Tags: android

Is it possible to develop an app for Javelin at an API level lower than 18 or JellyBean 4.3?

The Samsung Galaxy S3 we are using for the project will not update past Android Version 4.1.2.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Javelin is a BLE device, as such it requires your mobile device to be running Android OS 4.3+. Android 4.3 introduced BLE protocol per the link below.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

I would double check if you have the Samsung Galaxy S3. The phone should be able to update to JellyBean 4.3.

Follow this link here to update to JellyBean 4.3:

http://wccftech.com/update-galaxy-s3-i9300-latest-android-43-jelly-bean-official-firmware/

If you are using a Mac you can use this link:

http://androidfact.com/update-galaxy-s3-through-kies/